# Why @Transactional doesn't work in my cord?

Tags: spring, transactions, mybatis, spring-transactions

I am using Spring + mybatis in my project, and want to use `@Transactional` to start a transaction, so I add some configuration code in my `dataSource.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="true">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="oracletransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="oracletransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracledataSourceWrite"/>
    </bean>
```

and this is part of my test code:

```
@Transactional
    public void testTransaction() throws Exception {
          // insert operation 1 without error
          // insert operation 2 with exception ,on purpose, such as some data too long for column in mysql
}
```

After run the test, `insert operation 1` insert into database successfully, and `insert operation 2` fail, thus `Transaction` doesn't work any more, can anyone help me???

I test it in my main function.

**Edit:**
finally, I changed to another way with transaction by using `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`.

Comment: Are you using the spring test framework? or is that a plain unit test?

Comment: Are you sure the failure of operation2 is related to operation1?  Can you omit operation 1 and successfully perform operation2?

Comment: just a comment, have you tried enable the logging in org.springframework & org.hibernate

Comment: I just delete my answer because that I realize my mistakes.. Could you give more details about your testTransaction() function?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define like this

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Comment: Have, you added `@Repository` to your class? And have you added this package in `<context:component-scan>`.